# How to convert the Date into Epoch in iReport and Jasperserver

Tags: ireport, jasperserver

I want to create a report for login history between two dates.

The login history table has the following fields:

```
login_date  (data type is integer)
user_id     (data type is integer)
```

#### Sample records

```
|login_date |user_id|
+-----------+-------+
|1299954600 |   105 |
|1299954600 |   105 |
|1299954600 |   105 |
|1299954600 |   105 |
|1301164200 |   114 |
|1301164200 |   106 |
|1301769000 |   110 |
|1301164200 |   106 |
|1301769000 |   106 |
|1301769000 |   106 |
|1301769000 |   106 |
|1302978600 |   102 |
|1302373800 |   112 |
|1302978600 |   111 |
|1302978600 |   111 |
|1302978601 |   111 |
```

**Note:** I have stored the login date in Epoch time.

I want to create the report for following query.

```
SELECT
  user_id,
  count(user_id)
FROM
  rep_time_tracking
WHERE
  login_date between 1301596200 AND 1303496940
GROUP BY 1;
```

I have added two parameters for run time parameter.

Example. `${FROM}` and `$P{TO}`, value expression is Date/Time.

Now the user selects the date and time using the input I want to convert into Epoch.

How to achieve this in iReport *and* JasperServer?

Comment: Your question is how to convert java.util. Date/Time to Epoch time? (In ireport or JasperServer)

Comment: Yes.. now I have changes my query like this .SELECT user_id,count(user_id) from rep_time_tracking where login_date between date_part('epoch','04/01/2011'::date)::int  and  date_part('epoch','04/23/2011'::date)::int group by 1; to achieve this, It is possible in iReport and JasperServer?

Answer (score 1):

Its pretty Simple, All You have to do is call a function on Date which is getTime() it gives you UTC time and then use it as Parameter in query.!

See the Screent Shot.
[image]